# Using ng-click in a rendered column of Datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datatable

I'm using a plain Datatable in AngularJS (not using any Angular-Datatable libraries). Everything seems good so far, except for one thing.

I have this datatable:

```
$scope.siInfoTable = $('#siInfoTable').DataTable({
            'columns': [
                {
                    "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
                        data =  '<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" ng-click="test()">TEST</button>';
                        return data;
                    }
                }]
        });
```

This is run inside a `$scope.load` method and is loaded before the page is rendered. When user clicks the rendered button in the datatable, it doesn't seem to recognize the `ng-click` directive.

Is there a way around here?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use the **`angular-datables`** angular library else mostly what will happen is.

1. Changes in your controller or directive will not be reflected in the output HTML.
2. Some errors may get thrown repeatedly.

To reduce the volume of issues you are facing. Here is a snippet using angular data tables.

Taken from [Angular Datatables Documentation](http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/archives/#!/withButtons)

---

```js
    angular.module('datatablesSampleApp', ['datatables', 'datatables.buttons']).
    controller('sampleCtrl', function($scope, DTOptionsBuilder) {
        $scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
          .withPaginationType('full_numbers') 
          .withDisplayLength(2)
          .withOption('order', [1, 'desc']).withButtons([{
        text: '<button class="btn">Some button</button>',
        key: '1',
        action: function(e, dt, node, config) {
          alert('Button activated');
        }
      }]);
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.1/css/jquery.dataTables.css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-datatables/0.6.2/angular-datatables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-datatables/0.6.2/plugins/buttons/angular-datatables.buttons.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="datatablesSampleApp">
    <div ng-controller="sampleCtrl">
        <table datatable dt-options="dtOptions">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>First name</th>
                    <th>Last name</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>Foo</td>
                    <td>Bar</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>123</td>
                    <td>Someone</td>
                    <td>Youknow</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>987</td>
                    <td>Iamout</td>
                    <td>Ofinspiration</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @christianleroy Did this answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

$Try to compile your html before affecting it to data, inject $compile into your controller

```
app.controller('mycontroller', ['$compile', ..., function($compile, ...)
```

And then compile your html

```
data =  $compile('<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" ng-click="test()">TEST</button>')($scope);
```